# Recommended joint compound for wall mounted tile backer boards

Tags: tile, backer-board

I’ve installed pro warm tile backer boards on my bathroom walls. What’s the recommended way to fill the joints before tiling over?

The Marmox guides say to use waterproof tape or joint compound. I was going to tape the joints and plaster over this. Are there any specific joint compounds I should use for this?

Comment: You do not say if it is for the shower or a waterproof situation. i have not use this product but the web site says  "Installation on walls


Working steps:
01. Frame walls
02. Fixing with screws and covering of joints with glass fibre mesh or sealing tape, embedded in a layer of **flexible tile adhesive**.
03. Once the adhesive has cured, tiles can be fixed and grouted.
04. Ready to use."

Comment: It’s for a shower. Yeah I read that but there’s some gaps between the boards. And I don’t want to buy a roll of waterproof tape